# How to fade the edge of a div with just CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this with just one div (no background images/foreground images/layers)?

Comment: is it ok to use an order list <ol> instead of a div? It would be semantically correct to me

Comment: This is just an example. There are actually complex items within that div.

Comment: `ol` or `div` doesn't matter in the context of your question.

Comment: Within <ol> its ok, just make the children il display: block;

Comment: How is <ol> relevant at all? All I am asking is whether an element can be blurred without layers at one end.

Comment: @antonpug I know that there's no practical difference, but I just prefer to ask before suggesting something that could be not suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 129):

You could overlap a pseudoelement with a gradient applied on it

```css
ol {
  border: 1px #d8d8d8 dashed;
  font: 2em/1.6em Arial;
  position: relative;
}

ol:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255, 1) 90%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
</ol>
```

Since `pointer-events` is set to `none` the text under the gradient will be also selectable/clickable.

---

### Update 03.2023

The same effect can be achieved with the `mask` property

```css
ol {
  --mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
      rgba(0,0,0, 1) 0,   rgba(0,0,0, 1) 40%, 
      rgba(0,0,0, 0) 95%, rgba(0,0,0, 0) 0
  ) 100% 50% / 100% 100% repeat-x;
  
  border: 1px #d8d8d8 dashed;
  font: 2em/1.6em Arial;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask); 
  mask: var(--mask);
  
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
  <li>item5</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Perfect...beat me to it by 30 seconds. +1

Comment: Browser support on pointer-events is rather weak btw. http://caniuse.com/#search=pointerevents

Comment: of course, if the text is supposed to contain links, buttons or input this solution is not suitable, anyway since it's a visual effect you may show it only on browser supporting that property.

Comment: I came here looking for a fade effect at the edge of a scrolling list—I assume the OP is trying to do something similar. I forked this Pen, wrapped the `ol` in a `div` and ended with the effect I'm looking for. http://codepen.io/1deadpixel/pen/XNXaMY

Comment: Is there any way to get a fade to transparent? This is a fade-to-white and I get that you can pretty much do any color, but preferably I'd like the opacity itself to adjust rather than putting an overlay on.

Comment: Beautiful stuff. Works really well. Nice and clean and customizable.

Comment: The second option with the mask is the best option I've seen, since it doesn't require you to provide any color, like in the first option. Having a different colored background (e.g. when using dark mode) doesn't make it look different! Thanks :)

Answer (score 18):

I (personally) find that using a secondary element as an "overlap" works pretty well. I do this by defining a new `tag`. This makes it really easy to add the desired *fade out* effect to any element you want using `<fade/>` at the end.

```css
div {
    position: relative;
}

fade {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;

    display: block;
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
  
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)
    100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
    text
    <br>
    text
    <br>
    text
    <fade/>
</div>
```

Giving the `fade` element an `absolute` position with a `gradient` background works just as expected. As long as you remember to set the parent's position to `relative`.

Comment: This only works if the content is sitting on a white container. If the color below it is anything else this will look weird. Of course it is possible to change the color to match the background but this becomes a problem if the background is not a solid color, such as a gradient of a picture.

Comment: This works well on a nav menu if you want to fade the edges. The other methods shown here prevent the user from clicking on the links. Of course you need two fade elements, one on each side. I tried so many different approaches until this one worked. Thanks @Aleksander Azizi!!

Answer (score 6):

```
<style>
.fade {
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    ); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
    );
}
</style>
```

Here is an example for you http://jsfiddle.net/nrgx7/

Comment: Thank you. However this doesn't answer my question. Your solution would require a second .fade element to be added to accommodate the fading.

Comment: Get rid of the div and just do it as pseudo element: http://jsfiddle.net/nrgx7/129/