# Can background color be inherited in a CSS gradient?

Tags: css

I'm implementing a scrollable area with "gradient" edges like this:

```css
.container {
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: .5em; /* for custom scrollbar, nevermind */
  height: .6em;
}
.container::before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    white,
    transparent 100%
  );
}
.container::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent,
    white 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
</div>
```

So far so good. What I don't like is the `white` color repeated twice (well, present at all): for instance, for dark theme I'll need to redefine this color. Sure, I can use variables, but I wonder: can I inherit the color from background somehow? May be with a shadow instead of background (but it sounds even more unlikely).

As you can see, just using inherit doesn't work:

```css
.container {
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: .5em;
  height: .6em;
}
.container::before {
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    white,
    transparent 100%
  );
}
.container::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent,
    unherit 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
</div>
```

Can I achieve this effect? How?

**PS** Using [mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9525215/3995261) like this affects the scrollbar, so it's not an acceptable solution (and hence this is not a duplicate question):

```css
.container {
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;

  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em calc(100% - 1em),
    transparent calc(100% - .5em));
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em calc(100% - 1em),
    transparent calc(100% - .5em));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
</div>
```

Notes about masking:

- the main "color" can be arbitrary – I used `red` for short;
- with just `linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, .5em, red, calc(100% - .5em), transparent)` "fading" was to blurred, to make it more abrupt, I've read [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients) more carefully, done some experiments, and found that shifting the edge of the transparent part of the mask solves the issue.

Comment: A `currentBackgroundColor` variable similar to `currentColor` has been requested and is being discussed [here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5292). For now, as you suggested yourself, using CSS Custom Properties is probably the only way to resolve this if you are looking for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the solution mentioned in the PS of the question affects the scrollbar, and it seems that `:before` and `:after` don't support background inheriting, I've come up with another one. Now I'm using a variable for background (so that I can change it for dark mode) and reusing that variable for the gradient (yeah, variables are out there for DRY!):

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: white;
  background: var(--bg-color);
}
.container {
  height: 5em;
  overflow: auto;

  position: relative;
}

.container::before,
.container::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: .5em;
  height: 1em;
}
.container::before {
  top: 0;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em
  );
  mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to top,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em
  );
}
.container::after {
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--bg-color);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em
  );
  mask-image: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    transparent .5em,
    red 1em
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
  <div class="content">content is here</div>
</div>
```

Sure, I'd prefer something like the mentioned [currentBackgroundColor](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5292), but it seems that there's no simpler solution than above for now.

Comment: *Ok, if you know what to look for, you can find that this was already discussed.* --> we call this a duplicate, if you find a solution somewhere else considering up-voting it instead of adding another Q/A

Comment: @TemaniAfif it is a _partial_ duplicate alright, but it took me quite a while before I found it, so I think posting the question as I had it initially is in fact helpful. Also, as you can see, the issue is not fully resolved because of the scroolbar fading, so _closing_ this question is not helpful