# Fixed positioned element above css mask-image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have scrollable content with mask-image. I need to use mask-image because I want to have transparency fadeout effect with every background color. Now I need to set **child** element with position fixed above the mask. Unfortunatelly I cannot because it seems that mask is still on top. Manipulating of z-index is not working

```css
.faded {
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, black 48px, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: green;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="faded">
  <div class="fixed-header">
    Fixed Header
  </div>
  1) Item 1 - Test<br />
  2) Item 2 - Test<br />
  3) Item 3 - Test<br />
  4) Item 4 - Test<br />
  5) Item 5 - Test<br />

  6) Item 6 - Test<br />
  7) Item 7 - Test<br />
  8) Item 8 - Test<br />
  9) Item 9 - Test<br />
  10) Item 10 - Test<br />

  11) Item 11 - Test<br />
  12) Item 12 - Test<br />
  13) Item 13 - Test<br />
  14) Item 14 - Test<br />
  15) Item 15 - Test<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The mask is always positioned above the component where it is applied.
Why don't you try removing your fixed-header from the mask ?

```css
.faded {
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, black 48px, black calc(100% - 48px), transparent 100%)
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: green;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixed-header">
    Fixed Header
  </div>
  <div class="faded">
    1) Item 1 - Test<br />
    2) Item 2 - Test<br />
    3) Item 3 - Test<br />
    4) Item 4 - Test<br />
    5) Item 5 - Test<br />

    6) Item 6 - Test<br />
    7) Item 7 - Test<br />
    8) Item 8 - Test<br />
    9) Item 9 - Test<br />
    10) Item 10 - Test<br />

    11) Item 11 - Test<br />
    12) Item 12 - Test<br />
    13) Item 13 - Test<br />
    14) Item 14 - Test<br />
    15) Item 15 - Test<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot because it is a part of react component when I can only put something inside it.